# What is the meaning of "<" and ">" in MIPS comments?

Tags: mips, spim

I have recently begun learning assembly via MIPS, and I noticed that for some reason, QtSpim removes anything inside comments **and** between angle brackets when showing the original source in the "Text" window:

```
[snip]
sll $0, $0, 0    # this text shows up in QtSpim
sll $0, $0, 0    # and this <but not this>
[snip]
```

Is this some comment annotating feature of MIPS itself I can't find anything about, or is it just a bizarre bug in QtSpim?

Comment: It's nothing whatsoever to do with MIPS. It's just some strange feature of your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

```
# if x < 0
```

That is a comment, to be read

> if x is less than zero

With regards to your comment about the lines following this comment being italicized, I'm going to guess it's some sort of bug in the syntax highlighting.  Have you tried simply removing the comment, or changing the comment to something that does not including the less than symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Well... # is the character to start a comment in MIPS, so everything after the # on that line should be ignored. It's possible that the editor is getting a bit confused and not handling the comment correctly. Or maybe there's just an unrelated reason for the italics...

Comment: I did already know that the `#` mark starts a comment (indeed, I wrote it myself =D), but after a little more experimentation, it turns out it's somehow related to matching `<>` tags. I've updated the question accordingly.